# How to resolve build issue in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using my app on api level 22. I need to change the api level to use the in app purchase functionality. When I change the target version from 20 to 21 then clean the project, I found that there are many error messages. the reason is on the clean the gen folder not creating the required files.

While when I change the target version from 21 to 20 it is working fine.

Comment: you need to post the errors that come in the question

Comment: Please post the logcat erros, console errors